# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges error in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

I have an issue in my MVC project. To sum, I wanted my ASP.NET MVC project to use two different databases. These two databases are identical, namely

a) number of tables,

b) name of the tables,

c) column structure of tables are same. One of them is production database, another one is test database.

As you know, production database connection information is defined in the App.Config of the data application:

```
<add name="SampleEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/VeriKlasoru.CptModel.csdl|res://*/VeriKlasoru.CptModel.ssdl|res://*/VeriKlasoru.CptModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=SOURCE;PASSWORD=PASSWORD;USER ID=USERID&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I add test database connection information just beneath it:

```
<add name="SampleEntitiesTest" connectionString="metadata=res://*/VeriKlasoru.CptModel.csdl|res://*/VeriKlasoru.CptModel.ssdl|res://*/VeriKlasoru.CptModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=SOURCE;PASSWORD=PASSWORDTEST;USER ID=USERIDTEST&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and I changed the edmx file's code behind just like that:

```
    public CptEntities()
        : base("name=SampleEntitiesTest") //It was SampleEntities
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<CptEntities>(null);
    }
```

When I try to connect database, I am getting an error, *ORA-01031: insufficient privileges error*  How can I overcome it?

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1:**

We tried every privilege option, but no solution. Only solution we can find is seperating the source code into three different folders, "Dev", "Test" and "Live". I copy every code item into Test folder and I delete edmx file and I recreate it in the Test folder, and it works.

Comment: Having similar number of tables and names does't make two databases identical. You have to check whether the connecting user has appropriate privileges on the test database that you are trying to connecting. Use `select * from dba_role_privs where grantee='USERTEST'` query to check the granted privileges for the user.

Comment: Have you executed `GRANT ALL ON TO [USERIDTEST] WITH GRANT OPTION` on other entity DB to give `USERIDTEST` full privileges on it? 01031 error may thrown from EF was trying to create table under given user which has insufficent privilege.

Comment: Jsapkota;
"select * from dba_role_privs"  throws me an error "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" error. Is there any problem with the query?

Comment: Try using `GRANT SELECT ON dba_role_privs TO [USERIDTEST];` then execute the SELECT query given by @JSapkota (use `sys.dba_role_privs` on FROM clause if it still throwing 00942). Again, this is related to permission issue, thus you need to execute proper GRANT statements on Oracle DB side.

Comment: Thank you, but your answers are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are not authorized to login oracle.(`create session privileges`)

check your `privileges`  like this:

```
select * from dba_role_privs where grantee='your_user'
```

Comment: No, it is not a privileges issue, neither create session, nor admin privilege.